Upper bound on area of $f(D)$ for non-injective holomorphic functions
Let $D$ be the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be an injective holomorpic function. Suppose that $f$ has Taylor series representation with coefficients $(c_n)$. Then, the area of $f(D)$ is:
$$\int_D | f'(z)|^2 dz $$
by the Jacobian formula.
It has been my intention to prove that this gives an upper bound if $f$ is not necessarily injective, which seems obvious, but I do not think it is trivial. I would like to know if my proof is correct, and even more so, if it should be improved in any way.
Proof of statement
Let $f$ be as described. By the principle of isolated zeroes, the zeroes of $f'$, denoted now by $Z$, form a discrete set, which is therefore countable. We can find a mesh $M$ such that:

the Lebesgue measure of $M$ is $0$
$D \setminus M$ is the union of countably many disjoint (solid) triangles
the total measure of the triangles intersecting $Z$ have radius at most $\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{4}},...$ for some enumeration of $Z$
no two triangles in $\mathcal{T}_Z$ are adjacent

where $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of triangles comprising $D \setminus M$ and $\mathcal{T}_Z$ is the set of triangles intersecting $Z$.
By the local degree theorem, every point $w$ not in $Z$ has an injectivity radius $r_w$ and $w \mapsto r_w$ is continuous. In particular, $r$ attains a non-zero minimum on the compact set $D \setminus \bigcup_{\mathcal{T}_Z} T$.
Thus, we can refine the mesh further so that $f$ is injective on every $T \in \mathcal{T} \setminus \mathcal{T}_Z$. Now, if we let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure:
$$\lambda(f(D)) \le \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}} \lambda(f(T))$$
since $M$ has measure $0$.
$$\le \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}\setminus \mathcal{T}_Z} \lambda(f(T)) + \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_Z} \lambda(f(T))$$
$$ \le \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}\setminus \mathcal{T}_Z} \lambda(f(T)) + \pi || f'||^2_{\infty}\varepsilon$$
by the mean value inequality.
$$\le \int_{\bigcup_{\mathcal{T}\setminus \mathcal{T}_Z} T} |f'(z)|^2 dz + \pi || f'||^2_{\infty}\varepsilon$$
by injectivity.
$$\le \int_D |f'(z)|^2 dz + \pi || f'||^2_{\infty}\varepsilon$$
$$\le \int_D |f'(z)|^2 dz$$
after taking the infimum over $\varepsilon$, as required.
I found it unintuitive to remove the points at which $f$ is non-injective; this is where any inequality would be most pronounced. Is it necessary? I think I can see the requirement that $f'$ is bounded is probably not necessary if we add more conditions on the triangles intersecting $Z$.

note that $f$ can be non injective and $f'$ never vanishes (see $e^{z/100}$ on the unit circle)

@Conrad You're right, I did have some awareness of "non-local" non-injectivity, but I now realise that I implemented the local degree theorem incorrectly. Thanks for the correction. I think it can be fixed with modifications to the mesh, although it seems fiddly. Do you think the argument as a whole works?

@Conrad I think I found a workaround. I was frustrated by a failure to find quantitative estimates for the injectivity radius in terms of the derivative. Do you know any which exist? Bloch's theorem seems close, but I think it is not quite the same.

Your argument is more or less correct though it can be improved a little but the idea is correct; as for the other question, the answer is no which can be seen by looking at $\frac{e^{nz}-1}{n}$ which has derivative $1$ at zero, but $f(0)=f(2\pi i/n)$

@Conrad Thanks for the counterexample. I appreciate that the argument as presented here is not the most rigorous, but I feel confident that I can figure out the details. Did you have any other improvements in mind?

eliminate the critical points (isolated countable so doen;t matter either for the measure of $D$ or of its image, hence assume $f'$ doesn't vanish) and use that $f$ is absolutely continuous wr Lebesgue measure in the plane to reduce to a finite $\epsilon$ cover where $f$ is injective on each piece -

@Conrad I see, there was no need for the nuisance of a mesh in my argument. Thanks!

@Conrad, J. S.: I think that a rigorous proof of $\operatorname{area}(f(D)) \le \int_D | f'(z)|^2 dz$ would be an interesting and useful contribution to this site. I have started a bounty as a small incentive :)

As a matter of fact the result follows from the theorem: If $f: G \to \Omega$ is a surjective analytic function and for each $\xi$ in $\Omega$, $n(\xi)$ is number of points in $f^{-1}(\xi)$, then $\int_{G}|f'|^2 dA = \int_{\Omega}n(\xi) dA(\xi)$. It can be found with proof, for example, in John B. Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable II", 1995. p.13, Theorem 2.14.

@AndreyZherdev: That is exactly what I am looking for (and now I have the feeling that I have seen the formula before, but I do not remember where). Unfortunately I do not own Conway's book or have access to it. An answer with a sketch of the proof would be appreciated!

@MartinR I’m glad to have gotten pretty close to a proof by Conway!

The result follows from the theorem (John B. Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable II", 1995. p.13, Theorem 2.14):

If $f: G \to \Omega$ is a surjective analytic function and for each $\xi$ in $\Omega$, $n(\xi)$ is the number of points in $f^{-1}(\xi)$, then
$$\int_{G}|f'|^2 dA = \int_{\Omega}n(\xi) dA(\xi).$$

Since $\text{Area}(\Omega) \le \int_{\Omega}n(\xi) dA(\xi)$, we obtain the desired result.
Here is the proof of this theorem from the referenced book with just a couple of minor corrections to avoid some typos and references.
Proof. Since $f$ is analytic, $\{z : f'(z) = 0\}$ is countable and its complement
in $G$ is an open set with the same measure. Thus without loss of generality
we may assume that $f'$ never vanishes; that is $f$ is locally one-to-one.
Thus for each $z$ in $G$ there are arbitrarily small disks centered at $z$ on
which $f$ is one-to-one. The collection of all such disks forms a Vitali cover
of G. By the Vitali Covering Theorem there are a countable number of
pairwise disjoint open disks $\{D_n\}$ such that $f$ is one-to-one on each $D_n$
and $\text{Area}(G \backslash \cup_{n} D_n) = 0$.
Put $\Lambda = \cup_{n}f(D_n) = f(\cup_n D_n)$. Because $f( \partial D_n)$ is a smooth curve,
$\text{Area}(\Omega) = \text{Area}(\Lambda)$. For $1 < k < \infty$, let $\Lambda_k = \{\xi \in \Lambda : n(\xi) = k \}$. So
$\text{Area}(\Lambda) = \sum_k \text{Area}(\Lambda_k)$. If $G_k = f^{-1}(\Lambda_k)$, then  we have
$$ \int_{G_k} |f'|^2 dA = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{D_n \cap G_k} |f'|^2 dA
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{Area}(f(D_n \cap G_k)) 
= k\text{Area}(\Lambda_k)$$
since $f$ is one-to-one on each $D_n$. Thus
$$ \int_{G} |f'|^2 dA = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{G_k} |f'|^2 dA = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\text{Area}(\Lambda_k) = \int_{\Omega} n(\xi) dA(\xi).$$

Thanks, Andrey. Personally, I was interested in this since $\int |f’|^2 dA = π \sum n |a_n|^2$, where the coefficients of $f$ are $(a_n)$. I guess there is no clear way to relate this to the coefficients anymore if $n(\xi)$ is not constant.
